# Reading text from image using Tesseract and OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

1) If the background is crystal clear, text is extracted using opencv but i am not able to process text for this image:

[image: Image to be processed]
<sub>(source: [bigbasket.com](https://www.bigbasket.com/media/uploads/pnw/l/MzExNDUyMDIzMw_3.jpg))</sub>

ideally it should give me "100% organic" "almond" at least.

2)To further complicate the problem i only want the results as "100% organic" "almond" and not anything that is written on the product.

For the image link output should be - "100% organic", "almond"

For the image link output shouldn't be - "100% organic" "almond" "royal" "organic" "bigbasket"

FYI - i am using pytesseract.image_to_string() method.

Comment: Can you share the code you are currently using to get the above mentioned output ?

Comment: Let’s assume this is a deterministic problem not involving magic and arm-waving. How do you think you can systematically differentiate the 100% Organic and almond from the other text?

Comment: @barny boss i don't have much idea to share but if we can eliminate the text present near the edges of the image and keep the text which is in the center it solves 90% cases.